# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Converter when importing jpa application context in webservice module

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, classpath

I'm getting the following error when calling the jpa module from my webservice module in my multi-module maven project.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/applicationContext-mysql.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Converter

I've added a resource import in my spring-ws-servlet.xml file in the webservice module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="org.learn.spring" />

  <sws:annotation-driven/>

  <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="osinvoke" portTypeName="EAIOSInvoke" locationUri="/osinvoke/" targetNamespace="http://spring.learn.com/eai/definitions">
    <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/osinvoke.xsd" />
  </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

  <import resource="classpath:/spring/applicationContext-mysql.xml" />
</beans>
```

And here is the applicationContext-mysql.xml file from the jpa module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

  <tx:annotation-driven />
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="org.learn.spring" />

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cmddb" />
    <property name="username" value="testdb" />
    <property name="password" value="testpass" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaData" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

The unit tests in jpa module are able to detect the application context and create the entity manager from the context file.  The webservice module is unable to create the entityManagerFactory object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching from TomEE to Tomcat fixed the classpath errors.  Researching the classpath issue further, there is a [maven plugin](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-maven-plugin.html) to help with [configuration of jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852035/how-to-use-tomee-with-hibernate) in TomEE. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your JPA provider requires JPA 2.1, and you don't have that jar in your CLASSPATH (instead you have an earlier JPA API jar). This sort of question has been asked many times on here

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat lib should have the same version of JPA as we add as the maven dependency. I was stuck with this issue for a day to figure this out.

Comment: basically the application class path should not have JPA jars, keep this to the server classpath. Ie, JPA jars must be "provided" in Maven. You can print the maven dependency tree to find whether these jars are added to application classpath. Tomcat 8 / Spring 5/ JPA  2.0 to JPA 3 upgrade.