# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Converter Exception using hibernate with tomee and maven

Tags: hibernate, maven, jta, openejb, apache-tomee

I have the following exception:

```
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /home/mmarnc/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.1/webapps/name_vorname: javax/persistence/Converter
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:896)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Converter
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.containsClassAnnotationsOfInterest(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:60)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:116)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.<init>(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:151)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:750)
    ... 18 more
```

The dependencies of my pom.xml are the following:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>resources-codemirror</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>openejb-jpa-integration</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

And I have followed the instructions of the link: [How to use TomEE with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852035/how-to-use-tomee-with-hibernate) Any ideas?

Comment: could you browse [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748998/noclassdeffounderror-javax-persistence-converter-when-importing-jpa-application) same problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Converter when importing jpa application context in webservice module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748998/noclassdeffounderror-javax-persistence-converter-when-importing-jpa-application)

Answer (score 2):

seems you used a JPA 2.1 version of hibernate without adding the missing classes, eighter downgrade hibernate to stay JPA 2.0 or add JPA 2.1 API in tomee

Comment: that is a valid solution with 1.7.x TomEE - wished 7.0.x would be released soon, to have JPA 2.1 support :)