# Error on my first hibernate program

Tags: java, hibernate

My hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <!-- Database connection settings -->
            <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateTutorial</property>
            <property name="connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="connection.password"></property>

            <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
            <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

            <!-- SQL dialect -->
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

            <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
            <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

            <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>

            <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

            <!-- Mention here all the model classes along with their package name -->
            <mapping class="hibernate.Student_Info"/>


        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Main class is:

```
package hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student_Info student = new Student_Info();
        student.setName("jeevan");
        student.setRollNo(1);
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(student);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();         
    }
    }
```

Model class is:

```
package hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Student_Information")
public class Student_Info
{
    @Id
    private int rollNo;
    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }
    public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    private String name;
}
```

And I am getting the error below:

```
Mar 25, 2016 4:00:27 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.6.Final}
Mar 25, 2016 4:00:27 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 25, 2016 4:00:27 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mar 25, 2016 4:00:27 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Mar 25, 2016 4:00:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Mar 25, 2016 4:00:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateTutorial]
Mar 25, 2016 4:00:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Mar 25, 2016 4:00:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Mar 25, 2016 4:00:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Mar 25, 2016 4:00:27 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Mar 25, 2016 4:00:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Converter
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.categorizeAnnotatedClass(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Converter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 10 more
```

I have all jar files in lib folder, but still it's not working and showing above in console.

Comment: Can you post the pom?

Comment: post JPA , Hibernate API Versions . possible to be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30554407/1897935

Answer (score 1):

add the following dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i am using myeclips and wamp server where i found the pom

Comment: If you not using maven for build, download the jar and add it to you classpath

Answer (score 0):

1. Add following dependency in your project
2. Update Maven dependency
3. Run as Maven clean
4. Clean your project with eclipse
5. Try this it will work

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
       <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```