# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory exception from nowhere

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, exception

I have a strange error appearing every time i want to deploy my application.
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.

My application is Java WEB application using JSF, EJB and JPA (Hibernate). All libs were downloaded by IDEA (no Maven in this project), all dependencies are shipped with .war file. I'm deploying to TomEE 7.0.2 on Windows 10.

Here are my configuration files involved in deploying: resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <Resource id="my_internet_shop_db" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        JdbcDriver  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_internet_shop?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=true
        UserName root
        Password alpine
        validationQuery = SELECT 1
        JtaManaged true
    </Resource>
</resources>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="my_internet_shop" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>my_internet_shop_db</jta-data-source>
        <class>Objects.Order.CartEntity</class>
        <class>Objects.User.ContactEntity</class>
        <class>Objects.Order.OrderEntity</class>
        <class>Objects.Product.ProductEntity</class>
        <class>Objects.Section.SectionEntity</class>
        <class>Objects.Service.ServiceEntity</class>
        <class>Objects.User.UserEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_internet_shop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="alpine"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And my stacktrace:

```
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: my_internet_shop] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: my_internet_shop] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:872)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: my_internet_shop] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.<init>(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:157)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:866)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: my_internet_shop] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:951)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:151)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:122)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:134)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not access BeanManager ListenerFactory class [org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl] to handle CDI extensions
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.ListenerFactoryBuilder.buildBeanManagerListenerFactory(ListenerFactoryBuilder.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.ListenerFactoryBuilder.buildStandardBeanManagerListenerFactory(ListenerFactoryBuilder.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.ListenerFactoryBuilder.buildListenerFactory(ListenerFactoryBuilder.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator.integrate(JpaIntegrator.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:878)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: On a thread without an initialized context nor a classloader mapping a deployed app
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:287)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.getContext(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:263)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:298)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansFinder.getSingletonInstance(WebBeansFinder.java:51)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansContext.getInstance(WebBeansContext.java:185)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansContext.currentInstance(WebBeansContext.java:203)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable$1.findBm(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:105)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable$1.invoke(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:96)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.<init>(ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.fromBeanManagerReference(ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.ListenerFactoryBuilder.buildBeanManagerListenerFactory(ListenerFactoryBuilder.java:80)
    ... 77 more
```

This is just a small part mentioning the exception. Here are the [full stacktrace & server logs](http://pastebin.com/GqvCCrYz)

All of the database stuff and JPA mapping are OK. Double-checked and refined to perfection. In fact, i was able to run my app on Tomcat 8.5.6 server, but it doesn't support EJB, so i need TomEE.

The root excpetion here is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: On a thread without an initialized context nor a classloader mapping a deployed app`. It appears in all of my Hibernate-JPA projects (even simple tests with only one entity and no space for error), so I believe this is the real server-side-configuration kind of problem.

However i wasn't able to find any clue about this exception neither on StackOverflow nor on the internet.

I'm looking forward for your help, would be glad to get any help and advice.

Comment: Thanks for the question - I experience the same issues here by upgrading from TomEE 7.0.1 to TomEE 7.0.2, Hibernate 5.2.4

Answer (score 12):

you can add in your persistence.xml

```
<property name="tomee.jpa.factory.lazy" value="true" />
```

or

```
<property name="tomee.jpa.cdi" value="false" />
```

if you don't need CDI/JPA integration

edit: first one will make the factory created on first use at runtime and second one just disable cdi. Both work cause you don't need CDI when JPA is initialized during startup (tomee creates the factory before starting cdi cause cdi can rely on it - chicken egg problem)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and explain in greater detail what the difference between both properties is and/or provide a link to official documentation by Apache TomEE project? Thx in advance.

Comment: `tomee.jpa.factory.lazy` works for me. And I don't like openejb/openjpa.