# Unexpected Element in Persistence.xml Entitymanager inject not working

Tags: java, maven, jpa, persistence.xml, tomee-7

My program was working perfectly fine, till I started to use persistence and with the `EntityManager` `@Inject`.

There are a lot of errors thrown, but I think this one is the one most blocking.

It says something about an unexpected element, but I can't find anything useful online about it.

Log:

```
Connected to server
[2017-05-16 09:13:17,808] Artifact web-example:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
mei 16, 2017 9:13:18 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder deployWebApps
INFO: using default host: localhost
mei 16, 2017 9:13:18 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFO: ------------------------- localhost -> /
mei 16, 2017 9:13:18 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
WARNING: jar '/Users/renzo/development/school/dea/spotitube/app/target/web-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.persistence.Entity. It will be ignored.
mei 16, 2017 9:13:18 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
WARNING: jar '/Users/renzo/development/school/dea/spotitube/app/target/web-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.transaction.Transaction. It will be ignored.
mei 16, 2017 9:13:18 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: /Users/renzo/development/school/dea/spotitube/app/target/web-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT
mei 16, 2017 9:13:18 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ReadDescriptors deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load Persistence Unit from EAR: /Users/renzo/development/school/dea/spotitube/app/target/web-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT, module: file:/Users/renzo/development/school/dea/spotitube/app/target/web-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/. Exception: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence"). Expected elements are <{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence>
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence"). Expected elements are <{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence>
```

/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit
            name="mysql"
            transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>
            nl.han.dea.domain.User
        </class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Spotitube?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="spotitube"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="java"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nl.han.dea</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>web-example</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem becomes apparent in this line of the log output:

> Exception: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence").
>
> Expected elements are <{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence

This tells us, that their is a mismatch with JPA versions 2.0 and 2.1. The reason for this conflict lies in the rather old version of Hibernate that you refer to in the `pom.xml` presented.

Hibernate 4.2.x only supports JPA 2.0, whereas TomEE 7.0.x expects a JPA 2.1 provider as you told it so with a `persistence.xml` as presented in your question:

> persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
>                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>                xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
>           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd
>   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
>                version="2.1">

For further details on JPA support of Hibernate, see [Hibernate ORM](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/) download page on which these information is listed.

**Solution**

Most likely, changing Hibernate's version to 4.3.x should cure some of the problems you encounter. Here is how the relevant dependency declaration should look like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

In case you want to modernize your application further, give Hibernate 5.2.x a try. For the current version, the dependency declaration looks like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency
```

Hope it helps.

**Add-On**

If you want to go for Hibernate 5.2.x in a TomEE >=7.0.3 setup, you are advised to add

```
<property name="tomee.jpa.cdi" value="false" />
```

to your `persistence.xml`, as otherwise the container will complain on injection issues on startup. For details, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40818396) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40843536).

Moreover, change the `<provider>` entry to the new/correct package like this:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```